# Python: scrape only one url from the same html format

Tags: python, html, scrape

html:

```
 <li class="dropdown menu-large menu_index_link"><a href="/MainPage" title="A">A</a></li>
 <li class="dropdown menu-large menu_index_link"><a href="/apple" title="1">1</a></li>
```

They have the same html format but I only need the second one, what should I do with this? Maybe use title to distinguish?

Code:

```
for item in soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'dropdown menu-large menu_index_link'}):
    for link in item.find_all('a'):
        href=link.get('href')   #print out both of the link
```

Problem solved as below:

```
for item in soup.find_all(attrs={'class':'dropdown menu-large menu_index_link'}):
        for link in item.find_all('a', {'title': "1"}):
            href=link.get('href')   #print out the link I want
```

Comment: what about `item.find_all('a', {'title': "1"})` ?

Comment: @anupsabraham works perfectly! thank you :)

Comment: Cool. Didn't that is the answer you were looking for. Will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that the `title` attribute for both the `a` tags are different. You can select the required item by including title filter in your `find_all`.

```
item.find_all('a', {'title': "1"})
```

Comment: One more question here (I hope it's okay!) If I have more than 5 titles in the same situation but this time I need three of them, Can I write them in one line too?

Comment: item.find_all('a', {'title' : '1', '2'})  I tried to do this but it's an error

Comment: Not quite sure what all items are you going to catch. But you can use regex to filter them. `item.find_all('a', {'title': re.compile(r"\d")})`

Comment: The above method should match all a tags with numerics in title.

Comment: More Specific, if my title is these choice: "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F" and I only want to extract from "B" and "E", I can use item.find_all('a', {'title': re.compile(r"\d")})? Thank you :D

Comment: You can edit the regex in `re.compile` to match whatever title you want.

Comment: item.find_all('a', {'title' : re.compile(r"\B\E")}) or item.find_all('a', {'title' : re.compile(r"\B",r"\E")}) these are not working. What I mean is extract them at the same time. (At the moment I only can extract data first from B, then do it again on E, but since their datas are in the same format, I want to do it at the same time.

Comment: `re.compile(r'[BE]')`